# Which java jdk i actually run when I installed two jdks

Tags: java, bash, environment-variables, sudo

I have installed two jdks, whose version are 1.7 and 1.8.
In my .bash_profile, I set JAVA_HOME variable with $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7). In bash shell I run java -version, it outputs 1.7, however when I run sudo java -version, it outputs 1.8. So which java i actually run.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a command using `sudo`, it runs with the environment of the specified user (or root if no user is specified).  So the environment variable set in your local shell is gone when `sudo` runs.

Comment: how the java executable binary is found. in my bash_profile i set JAVA_HOME, but when i run sudo java, which java i use and how it is found by system

Comment: The root user's profile is loaded, which overwrites any environment variables you have.  Take a look at root's bash_profile.

Comment: @onlyG Did this answer your question?